# Cron not working

Tags: cron

Wrote a short shell script "wallch.sh" to randomly change my desktop background:

```
DIR="/home/user/Wallpapers"
PIC=$(ls $DIR/*.jpg | shuf -n1)
FIL="file://"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri $FIL$PIC
```

And copied it to `/bin/`, then `sudo chmod 755 /bin/wallch.sh` to it.
This could easily run from terminal smoothly without any error.

However when I add a line in crontab (doing this from terminal as user), like:

```
* * * * * /bin/wallch.sh
```

It just wouldn't run. Theoretically it should have run every minute.

`/var/log/syslog` says:

```
Feb 25 19:36:01 user-Ubuntu CRON[11762]: (user) CMD (/bin/wallch.sh # JOB_ID_3)
Feb 25 19:36:01 user-Ubuntu CRON[11761]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 25 19:37:01 user-Ubuntu CRON[11790]: (user) CMD (/bin/wallch.sh # JOB_ID_3)
Feb 25 19:37:01 user-Ubuntu CRON[11789]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 25 19:38:01 user-Ubuntu CRON[11828]: (user) CMD (/bin/wallch.sh # JOB_ID_3)
Feb 25 19:38:01 user-Ubuntu CRON[11827]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

The script I wrote (please note that I changed the file name, now it is `/bin/wallch`. Also, I removed the comment lines beginning with `#` except the shebang):

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="/home/user/Wallpapers"
PIC=$(ls $DIR/*.jpg | shuf -n1)
FIL="file://"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri $FIL$PIC
```

The `stat /bin/wallch` output:

```
user@user-Ubuntu:~$ stat /bin/wallch
File: `/bin/wallch'
Size: 484           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 130389      Links: 1
Access: (4755/-rwsr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-02-26 11:03:01.727198732 -0600
Modify: 2013-02-26 10:37:46.727135926 -0600
Change: 2013-02-26 11:02:06.215196433 -0600
Birth: -
user@user-Ubuntu:~$
```

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can install any MTA package. If you have an SMTP server (MTA) anywhere already that you can use, choose `nullmailer`. Otherwise you could go with `postfix` (requires some work) or `courier-mta` which comes with sane defaults, too (and is somewhat easier for beginners, IMO).

The fixed-width names above are package names on Ubuntu. So `apt-get install <packagename>` will get you the MTA installed. The main issue seems to be that you configured no MTA and therefore `cron` cannot send mail. The job itself doesn't indicate error from the log output I can see.

Side-note: you could also suppress any output from your jobs by appending (to the job line):

```
> /dev/null 2>&1
```

... and even suppress error exit codes with appending (further):

```
|| /bin/true
```

... I wouldn't recommend it, however. Also setting `MAILTO` in your `crontab` (see `man 5 crontab`) is another option here. But it's kinda "global" to the respective `crontab`:

```
MAILTO=""
```

---

What `cron` mails is the output (stdout/stderr, if it finds an MTA that is) of the job it ran. And it does that by default, yes. Also error exit codes (non-zero) will result in the output being mailed.

However, it also needs to be able to run the job, which in all cases requires that the file be executable (`chmod a+x ...`) or that, in case of a script, you prepend the path to the script interpreter and that in, case of a script, a proper hashbang line exists at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. But I still have a question: does cron have to send mails each time it performs the scheduled task? From my script you can see not even once was mail/MTA mentioned...

Comment: Besides, I remember once I added the `>/dev/null 2>&1` option with `gnome-schedule` but it did not work either...

Comment: @Kazzantra: in this case your question is worded *very very badly*. My crystal ball is in repair, so I couldn't see what exactly you were asking before your comment. See my edit to my answer. Feel free to edit your question to reflect your change of mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, but it still does not work. For this script, I did `chmod 755` to it, and also tried to prepend `/bin/sh` to it, however none worked. I actually do not need any output info from it, since it changes my desktop background every minute and I can see it at once if it works. `>/dev/null 2>&1` and `>/dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/true` did not work either.

Comment: Then why don't you set `MAILTO=""` and make sure your script doesn't leak a non-zero error code? It *is* all in my answer.

Comment: Hi 0xC0000022L, I just tried `MAILTO=""`, and still I don't see a change in my desktop background. The `syslog` says: `Feb 26 12:09:01 user-Ubuntu CRON[4098]: (root) CMD (user /bin/wallch)` without any error code.

Comment: Would it be the script itself? It can run from a terminal as `user` flawlessly with no error code at all, but would there be any mistake when running as `root` by cron?

Comment: @Kazzantra: could you post the script or relevant parts ... e.g. first line? Also include the output of `stat /bin/wallch.sh`. What I don't get is that in one instance you write `/bin/wallch.sh` in the other `/bin/wallch`. You sure there isn't a typo somewhere?

Comment: Hi 0xC0000022L, okay I will post the script by editing the original post. The `/bin/wallch` issue is because I deleted the extension name in order to avoid any potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this cron line instead

`* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf /bin/wallch.sh`

could also use */2 in the hour column for a background change every two hours (all even hours)

Offtopic advice: this is not a rule just a form to keep the scripts apart, use `/usr/local/bin` for you admin scripts. :)